# How to avoid c# generic type change it to base class type?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying write a code that can the set property value through the lambda expression.

"Property 'System.String Name' is not defined for type 'UniTest.weapon'" exception.

```
public abstract class weapon{}

public class sword:weapon
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;set;
    }
}

public static void SetPropertyValueByLambda<K, V>(K obj,V value,PropertyInfo property)
{           
    ParameterExpression targetExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(K), "target");
    ParameterExpression valueExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(V), "value");
    MemberExpression propertyExp = Expression.Property(targetExp, property);
    BinaryExpression assignExp = Expression.Assign(propertyExp, valueExp);
    Action<K, V> active = Expression.Lambda<Action<K, V>>
            (assignExp, targetExp, valueExp).Compile();
    active(obj, value);
 }

weapon weapon = new sword();
PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(sword).GetProperties().Where(K => K.Name == "Name").ToList()[0];
//set value to object
SetPropertyValueByLambda(weapon, "sword", propInfo);
//propInfo.SetValue(weapon, "sword", null);(reflection)
```

When I call the SetPropertyValueByLambda method, the K,V type convert to WEAPON and STRING, `MemberExpression propertyExp = Expression.Property(targetExp, property);` statement will throw a "Property 'System.String Name' is not defined for type 'UniTest.weapon'" exception.

In my think, call the `SetPropertyValueByLambda<K, V>` method cand with pass the weapon parameter,the K may be is SWORD type.if I change `SetPropertyValueByLambda(weapon, "sword", propInfo);` to Reflection method:`propInfo.SetValue(weapon, "sword", null);`will can success.

so what can I do something let the above code can run in the lambda expression.thinks.

BTW, I can't move the Name property to Weapon class from the Sword class.

Comment: Why did you decide to use reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your implementation code:

```
weapon weapon = new sword();
PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(sword).GetProperties().Where(K => K.Name == "Name").ToList()[0];
//set value to object
SetPropertyValueByLambda(weapon, "sword", propInfo);
//propInfo.SetValue(weapon, "sword", null);(reflection)
```

The variable 'weapon' is of type 'weapon' which does not define the name property. If you need it to be a sword then use a sword.

```
sword weapon = new sword();
PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(sword).GetProperties().Where(K => K.Name == "Name").ToList()[0];
//set value to object
SetPropertyValueByLambda(weapon, "sword", propInfo);
//propInfo.SetValue(weapon, "sword", null);(reflection)
```

I realize this doesn't solve your problem, but the underlying issue here is your object model. If you need to generically interact with your objects then they need to share a common interface that defines the properties/methods you want to be available.

Comment: You mean they must have a common interface.

Comment: @babcock,thanks.actually,weapon weapon = new sword() here is my dynamic create an instance of object which all inherit a Weapon,i don't know which class inherit Weapon,after instance ,i need set the value to it,it was similarly to the ConfigurationElement and ConfigurationManager.GetSection in .NET.

Comment: @user902408: The point is the same. If you need to be able to consistently access a property from children types of 'weapon' then weapon must expose them as properties.

Comment: @babcock,yes,i understand.but for example:ConfigurationA and ConfigurationB class both inherit the ConfigurationElement class.when GetSection method call,the ConfigurationManager don't be careful ConfigurationA and ConfigurationB class have what property,it use reflection technique to set property value ,that's my above problem if i change reflection to use lambda expression .

Comment: @user902408: The ConfigurationManager uses the factory pattern to dynamically instantiate the ConfigurationElement's that it finds in the config files. This would be implemented slightly different than the way you've laid out your design.

Comment: It seems that it has to be redesigned.

Comment: @Babcock,thanks.if i can't  solve then just only can use reflection technique:)

Comment: @user902408: It isn't that it can't be done, but doing so is not a small project.